# how to show the third line of multiple files

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a simple question. I am trying to check the 3rd line of multiple files in a folder, so I used this:

```
head -n 3 MiseqData/result2012/12* | tail -n 1
```

but this doesn't work obviously, because it only shows the third line of the last file. But I actually want to have last line of every file in the result2012 folder.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Also sorry just another questions,  is it also possible to show which file the particular third line belongs to?

like before the third line is shown, is it also possible to show the filename of each of the third line extracted from?

because if I used head or tail command, the filename is also shown.

thank you

Comment: Do you want third line of every file or last line?

Comment: third line, because i want to this for every file:  head -n 3 file_1.txt | tail -n 1

Comment: Jotne had a hunch about your second question. Please ask always only one question.

Comment: sorry about that, I will be careful next time and write all questions at once!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Awk, the variable `FNR` is the number of the "record" (line, by default) in the current file, so you can simply compare it to `3` to print the third line of each input file:

```
awk 'FNR == 3' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

A more optimized version for long files would skip to the next file on match, since you know there's only that one line where the condition is true:

```
awk 'FNR == 3 { print; nextfile }' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

However, not all Awks support `nextfile` (but it is also not exclusive to GNU Awk).

A more portable variant using your `head` and `tail` solution would be a loop in the shell:

```
for f in MiseqData/result2012/12*; do head -n 3 "$f" | tail -n 1; done
```

Or with `sed` (without GNU extensions, i.e., the `-s` argument):

```
for f in MiseqData/result2012/12*; do sed '3q;d' "$f"; done
```

**edit**: As for the additional question of how to print the name of each file, you need to explicitly print it for each file yourself, e.g.,

```
awk 'FNR == 3 { print FILENAME ": " $0; nextfile }' MiseqData/result2012/12*

for f in MiseqData/result2012/12*; do
    echo -n `basename "$f"`': '
    head -n 3 "$f" | tail -n 1
done

for f in MiseqData/result2012/12*; do
    echo -n "$f: "
    sed '3q;d' "$f"
done
```

Comment: your third commands can be applied to many situation! Thanks, this is what I needed!

Comment: Oh sorry is it possible to output the file name as well based on your third commands? because it does show every third line in the file but is it also possible to show which file the particular third line belongs to??

Comment: @john_w Just add whatever extra commands you want inside the `do`/`done` loop, e.g., `echo -n "$(basename "$f"): ";` after `do`.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -s -n '3p' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

or shorter

```
sed -s '3!d' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

From `man sed`:

> `-s`: consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
awk 'FNR==3' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

If you like the file name as well:

```
awk 'FNR==3 {print FILENAME,$0}' MiseqData/result2012/12*
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel -k sed -n '3p\;3q' {} ::: file1 file2 file3
```

Parallel applies the sed command to each file and returns the results in order.

N.B. All files will only be read upto the 3rd line.
Also,you may be tempted (as I was) to use:

```
sed -ns '3p;3q' file1 file2 file3
```

but this will only return the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro I am answering this question as we know FNR is used to check no of lines so we can run this command to get 3rd line of every file.

awk 'FNR==3' MiseqData/result2012/12*

Comment: What is the difference to the other two `awk` answers?

Comment: there is not much difference i am just explaining it

Comment: You shouldn't really create a new answer to explain an existing one, though. Once you have enough reputation, you can ask the author to add explanations in a comment, or you can edit the answer to add explanations (but be ready for the author to reject the edit if they don't like it).